# Build Wicket from sources using IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wicket

Warning: I never had used Maven so far and we don't want to use it in the near or mid future, so please don't tell me I have to learn it.

I want to build all Wicket jars and get also all dependent jars required for running Wicket.
I've cloned the Wicket Git repository, checked out the desired commit/tag/branch and created an IDEA project from an external model (IDEA 10.5), but how to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but if you want to build Wicket and work with real projects, you will need to learn Maven. The short answer is to run `mvn clean package` to get the jars in the target directories or `mvn clean install` to get it into your local maven repository.

Comment: We are using Wicket since ages without Maven. Works fine so far.

Comment: The thing is Wicket is made to be built using Maven, you can try to build it using another tool (`Gradle`, or even `Ant`), but I think it will cost you a lot of time

Comment: @Mike L.: please, do your self a favour and do not use an IDE for as an build tool. I just kind of survied a project that used Eclipse as such. Don't . go. down. that. path.

Comment: I only need to update the Wicket jars from time to time (e.g. one time in a half year). For the normal build process we are using ANT which works fine and I don't want to change that right now without a real need.

Comment: @MikeL. I think you've just found the real need to install Maven. If it is only one time per 6 months, I guess you can only remember the `mvn clean install` thing.

Comment: Right. You don't need to learn Maven at all. You wont change Wicket's pom.xml files. You will just run "mvn clean install". This is like running "ant" without bothering to know what your colleague did in build.xml.

Comment: @martin-g: I've tried `mvn clean install` but it fails in `org.apache.wicket.util.file.FilesTest`. Looks like the build does not work on Windows.

Comment: @MikeL. I think you are on an "unstable" branch, switch to a stable one and tests should be working fine (or launch `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`) if you want to skip them.